# Automatically add app to System Prefs>Security & Privacy>Accessibility in OS X 10.9

Tags: accessibility, osx-mavericks

My app needs to be added to the list of apps under System Prefs>Security & Privacy>Accessibility. In older versions of OSX, this was called access for assistive devices.  I do the following:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                         forKey:(NSString *)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt];
AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options);
```

As expected, a dialog shows up asking to deny access or open system prefs, and it seems to work fine. But my app doesn't get automatically added to the list of apps in system prefs. A bunch of other apps are already in there (XCode, Google Software Updater), and I didn't add them manually, so I know there's some programmatic way to add an app to that liset.

Is there some other call I need to make to cause that happen? Users won't figure out to drag an icon into that list.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I guess it's a matter of properly signing your app.